# paintComponent overriding to draw on a panel

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

This is a noob question. 
We are being taught applets in class, and I was trying something on my own.

The following is the code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class controls extends JPanel{

@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50); // <-- draws an oval on the panel
}

}

 public class test extends JApplet{
public void init(){
    final JPanel stage = new JPanel();
    final JPanel controlPanel = new controls();
    final JPanel banner = new JPanel();
    final JLabel name = new JLabel("Test", JLabel.CENTER);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    banner.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    banner.add(name);
    this.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
}
```

As far as I understand, paintComponent() need not be called explicitly.
The controls class works well when used alone.

I mean the following code works.

```
public class test extends JApplet{
public void init(){
    JPanel controlPanel = new controls();
    this.add(controlPanel);
}
}
```

I am not able to understand the difference. Why does the same code work in this case, and not in the previous?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Which code works and which doesn't? What happens when you run the code that doesn't work?

Comment: @MichaelMyers: The code without the layout works. The one with the layout displays the banner panel but not the controls panel whose object I created in the test class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` (and return a `new Dimension`) in the `controls` class. When putting components in `WEST` the width will be determined by the preferredSize. If you don't override `getPreferredSize`, the preferred size will be 0. The `CENTER` will take up the rest of the space, after the `WEST`, ect is calculated. The second case works because it is in the `CENTER` of the default `BorderLayout`

Comment: I added 
`public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
     return new Dimension(50,50);
    }` in the controls class. But it still doesn't render the panel. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try it with `100`. Can't figure out why 50 wont work

Comment: Oh it's because the location of the circle you are drawing. If the size of the panel is 50, and you are starting to draw at 50, the circle will be outside the size of the panel. You can use `50, 50`, if you draw at `0, 0, 50, 50`. But you should make the size of the panel, as big as you want the entire drawing surface to be